# Docker-compose service(sonarqube) can't access other services(postgres)

Tags: postgresql, docker, docker-compose, sonarqube

I've the following sonarqube+postgres docker-compose file. It works fine on my local machines on both `Docker for Windows` and `Docker for Mac`.

But when I deploy it on our live server (Ubuntu 18.04), sonarqube can not access postgres and I get the following Error in sonarqube container logs:

Any idea why this happens on the live server?

These are Docker and Docker-Compose versions:

**Local Machine**

*Docker version 18.09.2, build 6247962*

*Docker-compose version 1.23.2, build 1110ad01*

**Server**

*Docker version 18.09.6, build 481bc77*

*Docker-compose version 1.24.0, build 0aa5906*

```
version: "3.5"
services:
  sonarqube:
    image: sonarqube:7.7-community    
    ports:
    - "9000:9000"
    depends_on:
    - db
    networks:
    - sonarnet
    environment:
    - SONARQUBE_JDBC_URL=jdbc:postgresql://db:5432/sonar
    - SONARQUBE_JDBC_USERNAME=sonar
    - SONARQUBE_JDBC_PASSWORD=sonar
    - sonar.forceAuthentication=true
    volumes:
    - sonarqubeConf:/opt/sonarqube/conf
    - sonarqubeData:/opt/sonarqube/data
    - sonarqubeBundledPlugins:/opt/sonarqube/lib/bundled-plugins
    - sonarqubeLogs:/opt/sonarqube/logs
  db:
    image: postgres
    networks:
    - sonarnet
    environment:
    - POSTGRES_USER=sonar
    - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=sonar
    volumes:
    - postgresql:/var/lib/postgresql
    - postgresqlData:/var/lib/postgresql/data      
networks:
  sonarnet:
    driver: bridge
volumes:
  sonarqubeConf:
    name: sonarqubeConf
    driver: local
  sonarqubeData:
    name: sonarqubeData
    driver: local 
  sonarqubeBundledPlugins:
    name: sonarqubeBundled
    driver: local
  sonarqubeLogs:
    name: sonarqubeLogs
    driver: local
  postgresql:
    name: postgresql
    driver: local
  postgresqlData:
    name: postgresqlData
    driver: local
```

**I get the following  error in sonarqube container logs:**

```
SonarQube Server / 7.7.0.23042 / 1dcac8b8de36b377a1810cc8f1c4c31744e12729
sonarqube_1  | 2019.06.13 09:16:13 INFO  web[][o.sonar.db.Database] Create JDBC data source for jdbc:postgresql://db:5432/sonar
sonarqube_1  | 2019.06.13 09:16:23 ERROR web[][o.s.s.p.Platform] Web server startup failed
sonarqube_1  | java.lang.IllegalStateException: Can not connect to database. Please check connectivity and settings (see the properties prefixed by 'sonar.jdbc.').
```

**postgres container logs**

```
db_1         | 2019-06-13 11:18:36.548 UTC [1] LOG:  listening on IPv4 address "0.0.0.0", port 5432
db_1         | 2019-06-13 11:18:36.548 UTC [1] LOG:  listening on IPv6 address "::", port 5432
db_1         | 2019-06-13 11:18:36.561 UTC [1] LOG:  listening on Unix socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"
db_1         | 2019-06-13 11:18:36.579 UTC [24] LOG:  database system was shut down at 2019-06-13 11:18:35 UTC
db_1         | 2019-06-13 11:18:36.585 UTC [1] LOG:  database system is ready to accept connections
```

**More updates**

I added another service(jenkins) into the compose file and it’s up and running BUT I can’t access db service from jenkins service! for instance `ping db` does not work!!

When I get the network status of their bridge network, I can see that postgres and jenkins are both added but I even can’t `ping db` service by its IP address (ping 172.22.0.3) from inside jenkins service!
I suspect it’s sth related to the network between docker compose services.
Any Idea why it happens?

```
[
    {
        "Name": "pipeline_sonarnet",
        "Id": "754f1d4c5240fc34f0b34faffad61513b95c7c44f89fe15bd66efb7b79c4f53f",
        "Created": "2019-06-13T22:33:58.907722824+01:00",
        "Scope": "local",
        "Driver": "bridge",
        "EnableIPv6": false,
        "IPAM": {
            "Driver": "default",
            "Options": null,
            "Config": [
                {
                    "Subnet": "172.22.0.0/16",
                    "Gateway": "172.22.0.1"
                }
            ]
        },
        "Internal": false,
        "Attachable": true,
        "Ingress": false,
        "ConfigFrom": {
            "Network": ""
        },
        "ConfigOnly": false,
        "Containers": {
            "10e84761051c6e6044be3d976ee51dfd70c41c89dc38aab2d3ebcbeb9c2d6129": {
                "Name": "pipeline_db_1",
                "EndpointID": "d8e3b21ffa536c7c437479b5dbaf9a5946177ef87f73cf8e024610ebc8d3c1db",
                "MacAddress": "02:42:ac:16:00:03",
                "IPv4Address": "172.22.0.3/16",
                "IPv6Address": ""
            },
            "c1d042c77b3a0a6f519e11a5a812e38b95ac229244a5d6f28669c4132a104f30": {
                "Name": "pipeline_jenkins_1",
                "EndpointID": "e7592e5de8001ebf4df854c83670552bda78dad51191e215885fd7d58339d98b",
                "MacAddress": "02:42:ac:16:00:02",
                "IPv4Address": "172.22.0.2/16",
                "IPv6Address": ""
            }
        },
        "Options": {},
        "Labels": {
            "com.docker.compose.network": "sonarnet",
            "com.docker.compose.project": "pipeline",
            "com.docker.compose.version": "1.24.0"
        }
    }
]
```

Interesting! Other people also have the same problem but no answer:
https://forums.docker.com/t/docker-compose-works-on-my-machine-but-not-production/31410

Comment: Try restarting the sonarqube as mentioned here [sonar guide](https://github.com/SonarSource/docker-sonarqube/blob/master/recipes.md). This might help.

Comment: What versions of docker/docker-compose are present on your local machine and on the live server?

Comment: Restarting sonarqube doesn't  help. I edited the question and added docker and docker-compose versions.

Comment: What do the logs from the postgres container look like? Can you connect to postgres manually? Can you get a more verbose error message from sonarqube ("Can not connect to database"  is somewhat ambiguous)?

Comment: Incidentally, If just take the `docker-compose.yml` from your question and dump it to a file locally then run `docker-compose up`, it all seems to work.

Comment: Yes larsks, it works all ok locally, but when I run it on the server,it fails!! There should be sth related to Docker Network configs on the server I guess